# Creating clusters from adjacency matrix of Graph

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis, graph-theory

I am trying to separate clusters from a Graph. I have created adjacency matrix from the data set and now need a very good starting point for separating clusters from that adjacency matrix. Any help or tutorial please. Thanks.! I am attaching sample clustered graph as an example.

[Sample Clustering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ETYd.jpg)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do clustering on graphs (graph theory). I don't know how to generate sub-graphs from the given graph. I need a good starting point from where i can learn some basics.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't make it a programming question. It's a question to answer by looking at appropriate **textbooks** in a library and **searching for graph clustering** on the internet...

Comment: I have searched the internet but haven't found any tutorial or text book on it. If you can provide me link to some book . I would be very thankful.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/could-someone-suggest-me-a-good-introductory-book-or-an-article-on-graph-cluster